# Normalizing RGB image volumes for CNN

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a tensor of shape (5011, 224, 224, 3). Where there are 5011 samples of RGB images of size 244 by 244 pixels.

I am wanting to divide each of the 3 colour channels by 255 to normalise the training data.

I have seen `X_train = X_train / 255.0` for grayscale data, yet I do not really understand the syntax and therefore cannot figure it out for my case.

Comment: So, you don't understand what : `X_train = X_train / 255.0` is doing?

Comment: @Divakar Correct, that is when X_train is of dimensions (5011, 224, 224, 1). It ends up dividing all elements of each 224 by 224 array by 255, though I do not how/if that extends to the 3 dimensions of the RGB image too.

Comment: That's just broadcasting. Google for NumPy broadcasting.